# File uploading should not stop after leaving the page

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, file-upload

I am working on application that require file uploads, the files can be from 10-150 MB , it is working fine.

But once the file transfer is initiated and in between user leaves the pages and comes back to that pages, we have to start the uploading again.
So is there any way  through which file transfer should not stop even in case we leave the page.

I am using, jQuery , bootstrap and PHP for the application.

Comment: Yes you have to use the background processing. and if your application have huge amount of traffic you can think about gearman a specialist for background processing.

Comment: you can also use curl.

Comment: I think gearman / curl can only be used to process files once they are on server. The issue is that while uploading of file only if I move to some other link how to maintain the file transfer to be continued which has been started using javascript call

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can't send an upload request and leave the page peforming that request. Its the opposite of a download.

Most sites use a call to "window.open" on a button titled "upload" to open new window where the user can select the file to upload. The page in this window would be solely used for the upload process. When this page is submitted with ajax, a spinner of sorts would appear until that upload request is complete.

On the other hand (avoiding window.open), I assume you're using a form, so you could start the upload on another tab or something with target="_blank" on your form, but it may be a challenge to give information on what is occurring (the upload) in this new tab...

```
<form target="_blank" action="upload.php">
   <input type="file" name="upload1" ></input>
   <input type="submit" name="" value="">
</form>
```